# Unable to find any wifi connections

Tags: wi-fi, factory-reset, connection-issues, 4.3-jelly-bean, htc-one

I am currently using an HTC One.

Three weeks ago, I updated my phone to Android 4.3 and HTC Sense 5.5. Just three days ago, my HTC One can't find any Wi-Fi connections even if I am just sitting beside my Wi-Fi modem. I did a hardware recovery and reset my phone, but the problem is still there. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the wi-fi modem? Did you check if the password is still correct?